# C seg faults when assigning an array through function and printing the array

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I feel like two code snippets are doing the same thing, yet one seg faults

code 1:  this prints fine

```
int main(){
  int n = 3;
  int i;
  int *arr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
  int * can_arr;

  arr[0] = 3;
  arr[1] = 2;
  arr[2] = 1;
  arr[3] = 2;

  can_arr = arr; 
  for(i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    printf("%d ", can_arr[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

code 2: this seg faults when I print

```
void get_arr(int n, int *arr, int *can_arr){
  can_arr = arr;
}
int main(){
  int n = 3;
  int i;
  int *arr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
  int * can_arr;

  arr[0] = 3;
  arr[1] = 2;
  arr[2] = 1;
  arr[3] = 2;

get_arr(n, arr, can_arr);
for(i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    printf("%d ", can_arr[i]);
return 0;
}
```

why? both are doing can_arr = arr?  I am doing something else in my code that requires this array assignment.  I have just simplified it here. So why does it seg fault?

Comment: "code 1: this prints fine" - Um I beg to differ. `arr[3] = ...` that invokes *undefined behavior* all by itself. Your array is only **3** elements wide per you `malloc` sizing. Thus indexed only from `0..2`. Therefore, you code invokes *undefined behavior* and anything beyond that point is pointless to analyze.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `can_arr` from `main` is passed to the function `get_arr` by value. This means that the line:

```
can_arr = arr;
```

in that function has the effect that the local variable `can_arr` is assigned a value. But that variable is local to the function. So it will not affect the `can_arr` variable in `main`. So when you try to read from `can_arr` at the loop, `can_arr` will still be uninitialized.

Answer (score 2):

The array `arr` pointer in both examples has been allocated enough memory for 3 elements, with

```
int n = 3;
int *arr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
 // ...
arr[3] = 2;
```

But you are indexing a 4th element `arr[3]`. So whatever *appears* to work, is by luck.

Also the loop

```
for(i = 0; i <= n; i++)
```

is incorrect it should be

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
```